# How can I prevent the browser back button from reshowing my user notification?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, notifications, browser-cache

I've built a notification system for an ASP.NET MVC3 site I've been working on that lets the user know that various actions they performed happened successfully (a "pat on the back" message).  The solution works pretty well, but I have one issue that I would love to solve, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do so.

In a controller, I have the following example action methods:

```
<HttpGet()>
Public Function Edit(id As Guid) As ActionResult
    Return View(GetMyViewModel(id))
End Function

<HttpPost()>
Public Function Edit(...) As ActionResult
    ' Save updated ... information

    Me.TempData("UserMessage") = "Data Saved! You are truly an awesome user!"

    ' PRG back to Edit
    Return RedirectToAction("Edit")
End Function
```

Then in my view (razor layout) I have code that looks for the existence of the `"UserMessage"` key in the `TempData` collection, and if it exists I build out some JavaScript to present a growl-like notification for the user:

```
/* This only exists when we have something to show */
$(function () {
    showNotification([the message from TempData]); 
});
```

The growl-like message then either goes away over time or the user can click on the message to dismiss it.

So far so good, everything is working as expected.  User POSTs to `Edit`, they are RPGed back to `Edit`, the growl-like "*Data Saved! You are truly an awesome user!*" message is shown and dismissed.

If the user then navigates to another page and then hits the browser's back button, the browser then digs into its cache, resulting in the browser executing the same javascript, showing the user the same "*Data Saved! You are truly an awesome user!*" message again.  This confuses the heck out of the user thinking that, by clicking the back button, they just did something that caused yet another save (or whatever the message was).

I'm looking for a way, that once the notification is shown once, I can somehow prevent the notification from ever showing back up -- basically making it a "one time shot" message.  Things I have thought about are:

- including a `Guid` with every message, and using localStorage to store a list of shown message ids, and only if the message being requested doesn't already exist in the list of shown messages, show it.

  - I've thought of using a Cookie in the same way, but cringed at the idea that the cookie is needlessly blasted back to the server for future requests, plus the content of the cookie would need to be carefully considered and probably per-message anyhow.
- Instead of returning a message from the action method, return a `Guid` instead that points to a message in a database.  Then on page load, AJAX back to the server to get that message.  Once a message is got, it is deleted from the database, subsequent requests for that same message are handled by returning no message.
- include a `Guid` with every message, and before showing the message, AJAX back to the server to see if the message has already been shown.  Once the message is shown, AJAX back to the server to log that the message has been shown.

These all seem pretty untenable to me, but I could be convinced otherwise if someone wants to argue support for one of these.

Things I have tried:

- After the message is dismissed removing all traces of the DOM element.
- When the message is shown, set a jQuery `.data()` property on the message's DOM element to indicate that the message was shown, then before showing the message, make sure the `.data()` field doesn't exist.

These don't work because the browser caches pages at a point in time where both of these DOM changes happen afterwards.

Basically, I need a mechanism that my javascript can check to see if it really needs to show this given message, and if it does, show it, but then mark the message as shown so that if it is requested to be shown again, it doesn't.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can actually see this behavior in a similar way on the StackExchange sites themselves.  If you earn a badge, click the X to dismiss the notification, go to another page, then click the browser back button, you will be re-congratulated for earning the badge.  Same concept, only in my situation it's dangerous to reshow the message, unlike on StackExchange where it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a cookie to store the state of the message being shown, and check for the presence of the cookie when you attempt to show the message. If the cookie is there, you don't, and if it isn't, you do.
Seems like the logic for that would be pretty simple, as opposed to tracking GUIDs :)

```
// pseudocode
FUNCTION ShowMessage(args)
    // if the cookie is here, don't show the message
    IF StatusCookieIsPresent THEN RETURN

    // if the cookie isn't here, this is the first time showing the message
    ShowStatusMessage()

    // we showed the message, so set the cookie to make sure we don't
    // do it twice
    SetStatusCookie()
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Are you suggesting sending the message to the client in the form of a cookie?  And then deleting the cookie once shown?  Does that really feel like the proper use for a cookie?

Comment: no, I mean when you show the message, first check for the cookie, and if it's not there, you set it, so that you know that you already showed the message. if it is there, you've already shown the message, so continue without showing the message

Comment: So no concern here of multiple tabs causing multiple requests causing race conditions using the "go/no-go" cookie?  Seems fragile.  Then the other odd part of this solution is not only is the server providing a message, but a marker as well in the form of a cookie.  If I was going to go down this route, I don't know why the marker (cookie) wouldn't just be the message as well? (like my first comment.)

Comment: well, the cookie isn't shown to the user, so the cookie couldn't be the message. the cookie in this instance is basically a cross-page variable specific to the user's session

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2116/discussion-between-ckittel-and-nate-koppenhaver)

Comment: I ended up going with a solution like this.  I used the cookie for both indication that a message is to be shown, and it also housed the message (simple string for now).  As soon as the message is shown, the cookie is deleted.  Feels like a dirty use of cookies, but satisfied the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You also may take advantage of the fact that browsers remember on form-values, simple example:

```
<input id="notification" style="display:none" value="Data Saved!">
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    if($('#notification').val())
    {
      alert($('#notification').val());
      $('#notification').val('');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach and is very much along the same lines as the attempts I have tried before, so it fits my mindset pretty well.  I'll give this a shot and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in MVC, but I'll try helping you out.  I made a Hello World program 3 years ago and read a lot about it.  :-)  Are you using AJAX history in your page (using the # notation in the query string--the functionality Yahoo broke with their new YUI mail framework or forgot about when you click the back button--sends you to the login page haha)?  When you click the back button, are you coming from a different page or the same page to display your message?  I don't know enough about the Razor framework to help you out completely.

At first I thought you could easily disable cache on the page by using this code, but then I saw that you're using AJAX, so that's probably not a good enough solution.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

This would turn it off completely, but probably not a good solution for performance reasons.

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
</caching>
```

You could block the cache for the page displaying the user message from your collection, but I don't know what is happening in your AJAX to be sure.

```
Response.CacheControl = "No-Cache"
```

Not sure if MVC would respect this, but worth a try:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Category"] = true;

if (Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Category"])
{
   //...
}
```

Or, maybe that page is the donut with filling in the middle, and it's too filling (for the browser back button)--no pun intended.  Make it a donut-hole, and it might solve your issue.  Essentially you could implement a view control that contains the message your displaying.  And remove the cache policy from this view control.  I suppose it would work in theory.  Hopefully it works well in real life for you.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx

The OutputCache attribute (mentioned in that article) just controls cache for a given user control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx

Comment: pardon my semi-colons and brackets.. you're using VB.NET.  Use the [object].Item("Category") instead.  But my gut is telling me switching your diet to donut-holes will solve your issue.